# Bootstrap - Positioning Jasny Offcanvas element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an app that uses Bootstrap 3 and [Jasny](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas). My app has two navbars. One for the main nav items, and one for the child navigation items. In the main area of the app, I have an "add" button. When the user clicks the add button, I want to show some form elements using Jasny. In an attempt to do this, I'm using the code shown in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sfgv4jd/), which is this:

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar" style="background-color:#2e2e2e; border-radius:0rem;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/" style="color:white;">Welcome</a>        
      </div>
    </div>    
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <nav class="navbar" style="background-color:#5e5e5e; border-radius:0rem; position:relative; top:-20px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="/" style="color:white;">Subnav</a>        
      </div>
    </div>  
    </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">    
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#mySlideout">Add Item</button>

      <nav id="mySlideout" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-right offcanvas" role="navigation" style="width:400px;">
        <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Add New Item</a>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

        <form id="addForm" action="/add" method="post" role="form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Name">Name</label>  
                  <input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</nav>      
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

My challenge is in the positioning of the offcanvas panel when it slides in. It takes up the entire height of the screen, which is great. But, I want it to appear below the subnav. You can see what it looks like in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2sfgv4jd/). However, in reality, I'm trying to create something that looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Welcome                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Subnav                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| [add item]                                     | Add New Item   x |
|                                                +------------------+
|                                                | Name             |
|                                                | _______________  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                |                  |
|                                                | [save]  [cancel] |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The sketch above shows that the offcanvas panel's top is below the subnav container. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a margin to the submenu's top.

```
    <nav id="mySlideout" class="navmenu navmenu-default 
    navmenu-fixed-right offcanvas" role="navigation" 
style="width:400px; margin-top:100px;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fhz2peg6/